how to i use select option in script
im using script for dynamic adding row for table
but on of the option in my row should be in select from my database`
var items = 0;
function addItem(){
    items++;
    var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + items + "</td>";
        html += "<td><input class='form-control' name='machine[]' placeholder='machine'><td>";
        html += "<td><input class='form-control' name='meterstart[]' placeholder='meter start'><td>";
        html += "<td><input class='form-control' name='meterend[]' placeholder='meter end'><td>";
        html += "</tr>";

        document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML =  html;
}

`
this is my script
`
var items = 0;
function addItem(){
    items++;
    var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + items + "</td>";
        html += "<select class="form-control" name="machine" required="true">
                                        <option selected hidden>select machine</option>
                                        <?php 
                                        if($machine_list_result->num_rows > 0){
                                        while($mac = $machine_list_result->fetch_array()){
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $mac['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $mac['model']." -".$mac['machinenumber']; ?></option>
                                         <?php
                                            }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>";
        html += "<td><input class='form-control' name='meterstart[]' placeholder='meter start'><td>";
        html += "<td><input class='form-control' name='meterend[]' placeholder='meter end'><td>";
        html += "</tr>";

        document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML =  html;
}

   `
this what im trying to achieve

Please read the linked question. Then proceed to using an AJAX call to get that info
